# Why I'm getting ValueError while trying to unpad the data?

Tags: python, encryption, aes, valueerror, python-cryptography

In short, I'm developing an encrypted chat using ECDH + AES (source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/DividedByInfinity/encrypted_chat))

All encrypting and decrypting algorithms work just fine when I'm testing them separately.
They are also working when there is established **only one** connection to the server.
However, when there is more than one socket connected, I'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\!GitLab\chat\client.py", line 111, in listener
    plaintext = self.client_cred.decrypt(
  File "C:\!GitLab\chat\ecdh.py", line 105, in decrypt
    return unpadder.update(decrypted_data) + unpadder.finalize()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\padding.py", line 159, in finalize
    result = _byte_unpadding_check(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\padding.py", line 101, in _byte_unpadding_check
    raise ValueError("Invalid padding bytes.")
ValueError: Invalid padding bytes.
```

And here is encrypt my code of en/decryption:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from secrets import token_bytes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.hkdf import HKDF
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec

FORMAT = 'utf-8'
BLOCK_SIZE = 16


class DH:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ECDH = ec.generate_private_key(ec.SECP384R1(), default_backend())
        self.public_key = self.ECDH.public_key()

    def encrypt(self, public_key, plaintext):
        """
        IV = 16 bytes
        SALT = 16 bytes
        Shared key = 48 bytes
        Derived key = 32 bytes

        AES = 256 bits
        AES = 32 bytes

        Padder = 128 or 256 bits
        Padder = 16 or 32 bytes

        Ciphertext = IV + SALT + MSG

        :param public_key: another client public key
        :param plaintext: a text to be encrypted
        :return: encrypted ciphertext
        """
        IV = token_bytes(16)
        SALT = token_bytes(16)
        shared_key = self.ECDH.exchange(ec.ECDH(), public_key)

        derived_key = HKDF(
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=32,
            salt=SALT,
            info=None
        ).derive(shared_key)

        encryptor = Cipher(
            algorithms.AES(derived_key),
            modes.CBC(IV)
        ).encryptor()
        
        # unpadder = padding.PKCS7(256).unpadder()
        padder = padding.PKCS7(128).padder()
        padded_data = padder.update(plaintext.encode(FORMAT)) + padder.finalize()

        return IV + SALT + encryptor.update(padded_data) + encryptor.finalize()

    def decrypt(self, public_key, ciphertext):

        IV = ciphertext[:16]
        SALT = ciphertext[16:32]
        ciphertext = ciphertext[32:]

        shared_key = self.ECDH.exchange(ec.ECDH(), public_key)

        derived_key = HKDF(
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=32,
            salt=SALT,
            info=None
        ).derive(shared_key)

        decryptor = Cipher(
            algorithms.AES(derived_key),
            modes.CBC(IV)
        ).decryptor()

        decrypted_data = decryptor.update(ciphertext) + decryptor.finalize()
        
        # unpadder = padding.PKCS7(256).unpadder()
        unpadder = padding.PKCS7(128).unpadder()
        return unpadder.update(decrypted_data) + unpadder.finalize()
```

**The server** receives a message:

```
msg = current_client.recv(2048)
```

Decrypts it:

```
plaintext = self.serv_cred.decrypt(
                    self.connection_dic.get(current_client),
                    msg
                ).decode(FORMAT)
```

Encrypts it using the clients' pub keys (which are stored in a dictionary) and sends it to the chat members:

```
for client, pub_k in self.connection_dic.items():
    ciphertext = self.serv_cred.encrypt(pub_k, plaintext)
    client.send(ciphertext)
```

**The client-side** receives a message:

```
msg = self.client_socket.recv(2048)
```

Decodes it:

```
plaintext = self.client_cred.decrypt(
                            self.server_public,
                            msg
                        ).decode(FORMAT)
```

The client-side encryption looks like

```
ciphertext = self.client_cred.encrypt(
                    self.server_public,
                    msg
                )
```

The problem in more details:

Only **Client1** is connected to the server and sends a message:

```
msg = 'This is a test message, when only one socket is connected!'

enc IV b'\xc9\xc3`\xde\xe0^\x87\xf0O\x93\x11} \xb9\xeb\x8b'
enc SALT b'\xebs\\\xc8\x82\xcc\xcb\x88\xb1\xea\x99\x92lfQ\x18'
enc Shared b'\x82\xf0~\xa5-t\xf4\x00\xcb\xa9\xfd\x16\x10\x81l\xd7[qX]S\xe7@h3Fi\x14OIo\x8e\xd5_\xb7\xb4l\xb1\xc8L:\x9e;\xaf\xc6g\x17s'
enc Derived b'\xad\x0fW\x8bW[\x86^\xe3\xc2\xe5\x1a\xc0NoYn\x1e\x03\x19\x1d@!$zw]\xaf\x85\xa8\x9d\xc5'
enc Padded b'This is a test message, when only one socket is connected!\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06'
```

**Server** decrypts a message of Client1 without any problem:

```
dec IV b'\xc9\xc3`\xde\xe0^\x87\xf0O\x93\x11} \xb9\xeb\x8b'
dec SALT b'\xebs\\\xc8\x82\xcc\xcb\x88\xb1\xea\x99\x92lfQ\x18'
dec Ciphertext b'j*\xd8Q@ZGd\\9\xe3Qx;}\xfa\xa9e\x16\xb4\xd0\x8c\xab\xa0\xc2k\x11\x87\xf0F\xd5\xba\x8b\r\xf27\xd9\xa0\xf1\xd3Z\x99\x18!\xee\xa9\xd4\x8b\xfc\xf0\x19\x87\xee\x07\x91\xf1\x10\x8c\xfb\xd6\xb9\xf7\x1c\x86'
dec Shared b'\x82\xf0~\xa5-t\xf4\x00\xcb\xa9\xfd\x16\x10\x81l\xd7[qX]S\xe7@h3Fi\x14OIo\x8e\xd5_\xb7\xb4l\xb1\xc8L:\x9e;\xaf\xc6g\x17s'
dec Derived b'\xad\x0fW\x8bW[\x86^\xe3\xc2\xe5\x1a\xc0NoYn\x1e\x03\x19\x1d@!$zw]\xaf\x85\xa8\x9d\xc5'
dec Unpadded b'This is a test message, when only one socket is connected!'
alice says This is a test message, when only one socket is connected!
```

Now **Client2** is also connected and send a message:

```
msg = 'This is a test message when a second socket is trying to send a message!'

enc IV b';:H\xcdhh^ \xf9\x1d\xd2F\x85\xf6\x10\x04'
enc SALT b'\xfc)\x11\x1e\x97Co)\xd4\xd2\xb8MX\xe9\x08\xac'
enc Shared b'R\x8e\xca\xcf\xe0A\xd0{^)\x84\x82\xc1\xe1:7\xe9\x852e\xbf\x88k\xe5\xa0\x18V\x17?v;\xd1\xb9\xf76+[\xfd\xc1gp\xaa\nF\x9dY\xea\x82'
enc Derived b"\x18\xaa>\xe5Tt\x89TD\n\xc3V(t\xa2V\xc9\x08\xb5\x8a'\xe9\xaep\x19{\x94Ck1_b"
enc Padded b'This is a test message when a second socket is trying to send a message!\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08'
```

The server decrypts it (same IV, SALT, Shared and Derived key):

```
dec IV b';:H\xcdhh^ \xf9\x1d\xd2F\x85\xf6\x10\x04'
dec SALT b'\xfc)\x11\x1e\x97Co)\xd4\xd2\xb8MX\xe9\x08\xac'
dec Ciphertext b"\xaf'\x8a\xf2\x1d\x9dd\x93\xc4\xa9\xc5E\x19\xeb\xa9G\xde\xaeB\xefu\x7f\xc0SW\x0f\x15|\xa5\xee\x1b\x19P\xfa\x9a\x9f\x88\xf2\xf9\x10\xcaeGqr\xfc\xb6\xfb!\xc9}\xd8e\x14\xfa\xc4mx\xaev\x03%\xf8\xc4\xae\x9e\xe7\x16Z\x05\xc9\xcc\xc8\x05\xc5oR]\xecd"
dec Shared b'R\x8e\xca\xcf\xe0A\xd0{^)\x84\x82\xc1\xe1:7\xe9\x852e\xbf\x88k\xe5\xa0\x18V\x17?v;\xd1\xb9\xf76+[\xfd\xc1gp\xaa\nF\x9dY\xea\x82'
dec Derived b"\x18\xaa>\xe5Tt\x89TD\n\xc3V(t\xa2V\xc9\x08\xb5\x8a'\xe9\xaep\x19{\x94Ck1_b"
dec Unpadded b'This is a test message when a second socket is trying to send a message!'
```

The server encrypts a message and sends it to Client1:

```
msg = 'bob > This is a test message when a second socket is trying to send a message!'
enc IV b'\x82`Pv\xc3\xac\xac\x95\xd75\xd8\xd0XL\x10#'
enc SALT b'\xe5?y\xae\x1c\xbeMIs\x92\xe3\x0e1\x07B\xf1'
enc Shared b'\xc70}6Y\xac\xdc\xa4\x87\xba\x85\xc2\x0c\xd8\x88\x85_e#\x83f\xa1\xb0(\xac\x94s$t\xfd\x0benn\xa6\xbfz\x1a\x9byT\t\xa8\xffk\xd9\xcb\xb5'
enc Derived b'p\xef\xb2\xeb\xb9N\x0eQ\xa8q(\x04V\x91I\x841\xec\xdd\x04m\xd2\xef?\x02\x98f@B\x80\xd0\x16'
enc Padded b'bob > This is a test message when a second socket is trying to send a message!\x02\x02'
```

Client1 gets same IV and SALT from server. However he doesn't manage to generate same Shared key and ValueError is raised:

```
dec IV b'\x82`Pv\xc3\xac\xac\x95\xd75\xd8\xd0XL\x10#'
dec SALT b'\xe5?y\xae\x1c\xbeMIs\x92\xe3\x0e1\x07B\xf1'
dec Ciphertext b"\xd9\xcd)!\xde\xe8ks\x91kC\xe8\xba\x96\xe1\x1eyH.D\xff\xec\xbe\x82\xf3\x88\x0bT\xd56@A\x05\x12\xae\xb2\xcc\xd7y\x0fmb,\xad\xab\xf5\xc5\xdc\xe0%\xce\xf9`\x02\x80k\xa5\xad\xaa|7[%\x0e\x0bp\xb2\xeb\xb9'\xa3\x1b\xb8!i\xb6\xcbS\xe4\x1d"
dec Shared b'\x82\xf0~\xa5-t\xf4\x00\xcb\xa9\xfd\x16\x10\x81l\xd7[qX]S\xe7@h3Fi\x14OIo\x8e\xd5_\xb7\xb4l\xb1\xc8L:\x9e;\xaf\xc6g\x17s'
dec Derived b'Q\x0b\xe0\xcfY\x869b\x8a\xa7\x91\x02\xef\xb5\x01\xa9h_Z\x16I\xe5Qx\r\x93\xf3\xec-\xabK\x91'
ValueError
```

Comment: The unpadding problem indicates that probably either the ciphertext is corrupted (maybe a socket related issue) or the key is wrong. Both values could be logged in `client_cred.decrypt()` and checked.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you for answering! A client gets the same IV and SALT for decrypting, but cannot generate the correct Shared key. I've added an explanation of my problem. I also can put my code to GitHub if you like to help me. I would be very grateful to you :)

Comment: @Topaco Here is the link to the source code - [encrypted chat](https://github.com/DividedByInfinity/encrypted_chat).

Comment: Each time in `__init__`  you generate new secret key. Does init called once for the whole server/client lifetime?

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky If you are talking about the `class DH`, then the `__init__` is called every time a new connection is established.  The idea was to create a new private/public key pair for each new connection. Therefore, I don't initialize it in `__init__` of `class Server`, but simply "declare" it on the fly, so that it will be easier to use later. But, I think that I realized a problem with my code. The server is generating a new curve on each connection and declares it in its own `__init__`, which is wrong.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky So I need to find a solution to store all of those curves for each connection, or just use one curve for all of them. But, if I choose the last option and initialize it in `Server's __init__`, wouldn't it be "insecure"?

Comment: Not curve, but secret key, to which corresponds public key - point on curve :) Common practice is a single private/public keypair for the server. Later on you'll get to the point that you need to use signature to protect against MITM attack, and finally get to the TLS/SSL )

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky Thank you, Nickolay! The implementation for signing messages was already on my list :)